# call to undefined method illuminate database schema blueprint::blob()

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel 5 and in my first project when I try to migrate this I got this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Call to
>   undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::blob()

Comment: Maybe you should use binary() instead of blob(). Isn't that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such method `blob()`. It's [`binary()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#writing-migrations):

```
$table->binary('data'); // BLOB equivalent for the database
```